# How to deal with "confirmation" email for account you didn't set up?

Tags: email

I just got an email starting with:

> Welcome to Medix!  You can access your account at https://medixteam.bbo.bullhornstaffing.com/ and log in with your credentials as follows.

They then told me my credential were my email address, along with a temporary password they made me.

The thing is, I've never heard of Medix before. Apparently it's a company that does exist in my city, but I feel I'm being targeted for something malicious. Rather than click the link, I googled the words in it and found that the link is genuine, but it take you to a kinda sketchy looking login portal. What's more, the actual Medix page doesn't end with `bullhornstaffing.com`. There is a site which ends with this domain (without the `medixteam.bbo.`), but it's also a little sketchy looking.

Since they've given me a temporary password, I'm guessing they're pretending to actually be Medix, and they're waiting for me to update my password. Most users would use the same password as their email account, and it's game over from there.

I am not going to do this. Honestly, I'd rather just delete this email and move on, but does an email like this have implications that someone else may be attempting to impersonate me? I had similar trouble a while ago where I'd get emails confirming someone was trying to change the password on an old BattleNet account I'd not used in years. While I didn't really care if the account got hacked, I didn't want to leak any personal information that could compromise my email. Am I at a similar risk here?

Since I've never interacted with Medix before, I assume the only way I risk personal information is to interact with this email, but I don't know if there's something else I should do to protect myself than just delete the email.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would a stranger keep signing up to trading sites with my email address?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178110/why-would-a-stranger-keep-signing-up-to-trading-sites-with-my-email-address)

Comment: A side comment: password re-use is an absolute no-no, if really you're concerned about the security of the accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you personally, ignore it.

You may want to notify Medix that people are pulling these scams, but there is nothing technical or legal that Medix can do against it. You would only do them the favor of being informed (if not already) so that e.g. their support people know these are doing the rounds (if this campaign is large enough, they will get calls).